# Lumpsum investing in EPF/VPF

Tags: india, lump-sum, provident-fund

Currently, my employer deducts a basic amount from my pay for contribution toward EPF. I have voluntarily increased my share. I want to know if I can deposit a lumpsum into this account. If so, what is the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ByNo you cannot. You have to do this as part of your deductions from company.

You can request upto 100% of your basic salary into EPF. This can be changed every year or as per your company guide guidelines.

Comment: Can OP request a large percent be set aside for a few paychecks? (This is how I used to get my 401(k) deposits made early in the year)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there a source for this you can link to? @JoeTaxpayer: That is a good idea. Let me see if I can try that.